# Beaglebone Black CPU speed

Tags: clock-speed, beaglebone-black

I have a Beaglebone Black which runs Android. It has a 1GHz CPU. Bu when I read it's clock speed from adb I got 300MHz. I'm using following commands:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq
```

All of them returns 300000. I'm using Android image from Texas Instruments. Is tehere a problem? Is my Beaglebone Black running on 300MHz or is it just a system error? I try couple of apps to learn my CPU speed. All of them says 300MHz. But i think they are reading those files too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was beacause I power it up via USB. It sets it's own clock speed to 300MHz. When I power it up via 5VDC power supply, It runs on 1GHz.